# vagrant up provisioning before files sync

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, bundler, vagrant

I'm playing with vagrant for the first time and want to add it to our fairly large project. If I run the bootstrapping shell file I wrote though `vagrant ssh` after the files sync everything works great. However, after destroying the VM and doing a vagrant up for the first time causes a bunch of errors to occur on my Ubuntu 12.04 64bit machine once it hits `bundle install`

```
Bundler::GemfileNotFound


Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
```

I'm *assuming* this is because it gets to this before my `Gemfile` / `Gemfile.lock` finishes syncing. This might not be the case, but it seems like it is. How would I get around this?

Here's my full boostrap.sh script that runs on v up

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get -y install git

# Required for nokogiri
apt-get -y install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev

# Required for eventmachine
apt-get -y install build-essential

# Required for typhoeus
apt-get -y install libcurl3-dev

apt-get -y install ruby1.9.3
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming you are running that script with Vagrants shell provisioner?

Where is your gem file? Most probably it is in the same folder as your `Vagrantfile` on the host machine so try adding:

```
cd /vagrant
```

Before `bundle install` and it should work...